# Python: loops and strings

Tags: python

> Given two strings `s1` and `s2` of same length.
>
> Create a new string consisting of the last character of s1 followed by
>   the last character of s2, followed by the second to last character of
>   s1, followed by the second to last character of s2, and so on (in
>   other words the new string should consist of alternating characters of
>   the reverse of s1 and s2).
>
> For example,
>
> if `s1="hello"` and `s2="world"`,  then `s3` should be
>   `"odlllreohw"`.

I have tried this:

```
s3 = '' 
for i in range(0, min(len(s1), len(s2))):
    s3 = s3 + s1[i] + s2[i]
```

but I'm not sure how to have it reverse the letters from s1 and s2.

Comment: You can revserse a string with `reversed()` or you can index backwards with `range(len(s2), 0, -1)`.

Comment: You can reverse a string using slice notation with a negative step - ```s[::-1]```

Answer (score 1):

In python you can access a string or a list by using a negative value to offset from the end. For instance:

```
s3 = s3 + s1[-1] + s2[-2]
```

Will retrieve the last character of s1 and the second to last character of s2.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
str1="hello"
str2="world"
str3=""
for c,d in zip(reversed(str1),reversed(str2)):
     str3+=c+d
print (str3)
```

Output

```
odlllreohw
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use slice notation:

```
>>> str = "Hello"
>>> print str[::-1]
'olleH'
```

Answer (score 0):

One line solution could be:

```
s3="".join([s1[::-1][x]+s2[::-1][x] for x in range(len(s1))])
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem specification says that `s1` and `s2` have the same length, so your code should use that assumption. Sure, it's nice to have code that is robust and can cope properly with a wide range of input data, but it's also an important part of coding to write code that conforms to the specifications, otherwise you end up with bloated code that replicates work done by other parts of the program.

Your solution is very close to what you need, you just need to add `s1[i] + s2[i]` to the front of `s3`.

```
s1 = 'hello'
s2 = 'world'

s3 = '' 
for i in range(len(s1)):
    s3 = s1[i] + s2[i] + s3

print(s3)
```

**output**

```
odlllreohw
```

Note that I've used `range(len(s1))` instead of `range(0, len(s1))`. When a range starts from zero (and goes up with a step of 1) we can omit the `start` argument.

---

If you *did* need to handle input strings of unequal lengths you could handle that by using slicing to get the individual characters. This works because if you slice beyond the end of the string you get an empty string.

```
s1 = 'helloabc'
s2 = 'world'

s3 = '' 
for i in range(max(len(s1), len(s2))):
    s3 = s1[i:i+1] + s2[i:i+1] + s3

print(s3)
```

**output**

```
cbaodlllreohw
```

We get the same output if

```
s1 = 'hello'
s2 = 'worldabc'
```

---

But getting back to the case where we're assured that `s1` & `s2` have the same length, there are more Pythonic ways to do this. In Python, it's generally preferred to iterate directly over collections, rather than to iterate indirectly via indices. To iterate over two or more collections in parallel we use the `zip` function, which yields tuples of the iterators passed to it, stopping when the shortest iterator runs out of items.

```
s1 = 'hello'
s2 = 'world'

s3 = '' 
for u, v in zip(s1, s2):
    s3 = u + v + s3

print(s3)
```

**output**

```
odlllreohw
```

The "textbook" way to do this is to use a list comprehension to create a list of the pairs of characters from `s1` & `s2`, the `reversed` function to iterate backwards over that list, and the `str.join` method to combine them into a single string.

```
s3 = ''.join(reversed([u + v for u, v in zip(s1, s2)]))
```

We could also use extended slicing to reverse the list, but using the `reversed` iterator is more efficient since it doesn't need to build a copy of the list (of course, that doesn't matter much when the list is small).

```
s3 = ''.join([u + v for u, v in zip(s1, s2)][::-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to start from the last character and loop for `len(s1)` times.

```
s3 = ""
i=1
while i<=len(s1) :
    j=-i
    s3 = s3 + s1[j] + s2[j]
    i=i+1
```